# jquery slide down image on page load

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, uiimageview, slideup

I'm not experienced with jquery (or java script really), but trying to make an image (`img id=mike` ...) slide in when a page loads.

After looking through the jquery docs and trying Google queries, I have so far come up with this

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

$("#mike").load(function () {
      $(this).show("slide", { direction: "up" }, 2000);

});

  });
```

And applied the CSS `display:hidden` so it remains hidden until I want it to slide in on page load.

This doesn't seem to work unless I reload the page though.

Hoping someone could help me out with this please :)

Answer (score 2):

`.load()` isn't triggered if the image is retrieves from cache, depending on the browser, so you need to manually fire the event if the image is `complete`, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#mike").one('load', function () {
    $(this).show("slide", { direction: "up" }, 2000);
  }).each(function() {
    if(this.complete) $(this).load();
  });
});
```

The [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) ensures the event only fires once. The [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) loops though each element, only one in this case, and if it's already `complete` (which it would be if fetched from cache) fires the event to make sure it goes off (if it already fired, the `.one()` took care of it not sliding in twice).

Answer (score 0):

@Dean, you'll probably be best off using a combination of CSS and jQuery to do the job--this is to get around caching issues with images (see Nick's response for an explanation). Here's a rough example:

**CSS:**

```
#mike {
    display: block;
    margin: 0; padding: 0; /* Ignore this if you're using a reset.css */

    position: absolute;    /* Change this to relative based on the containing elements */
    top: 2000px;           /* Assumes you have an image that's 100px tall as an example */
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery( function(){
    $('#mike').animate({'top':'0'},255,'linear', function(){
        console.log('Done Animation);
    });
} );
```

You can also delay the animation a few seconds (or milliseconds) after page load:

```
jQuery( function(){
    // Delay the animation by 1 second after page load before animating.
    $('#mike').delay(1000).animate({'top':'0'},255,'linear', function(){
        console.log('Done Animation);
    });
} );
```