# sliding an image down when it appears

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function showImage() {
    var toggleImage = document.getElementById("loadingImage");
    if(toggleImage.style.display == "inline") {
        document.getElementById('loadingImage').style.display='none';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('loadingImage').style.display='inline';
        document.getElementById('loadingImage2').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('loadingImage3').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('loadingImage4').style.display='none';
    }
}

<img class="TeamMembersPictures" `enter code here`src="http://www.ishop247.co.uk/TeamPictures/Yvonne.jpg" onclick="showImage();"/>

<img id="loadingImage" src="http://www.ishop247.co.uk/TeamPictures/YvonneBG.jpg" style="display:none"/>
```

This is the code i have to display a new image on click of another image but what i want is for it to be a smooth slide down on the image that is displayed onclick

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674464/jquery-slide-down-image-on-page-load?

Answer (score 0):

Better yet, why not use CSS animation? Check out Animate.css (I have no affiliation) which allows you to simply include the css file at the top of the page and then do something like this...

```
<img src="whatever.png" class="animated bounceInDown"/>
```

You can download the css here...

http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Comment: i want to be able to click one image and another to appear thought, it works well i just need to be able to make it fade in and out ?

Comment: Update the question then as thats quite different from what you are asking.

Comment: sorry i found it hard to explain basically i have four images in a row on this page and want an image to appear below which i have got working with the code above and it removes a picture if it is there but what i want it to do is gradually put the image in, i found this code     $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#formA").click(function() {
        $("#formB").slideToggle("slow");
    });
}); but cant seem to get it to work for me

Comment: Please update the question... don't use the comments.

Comment: Sorry im new to this but i have now updated the question

Answer (score 0):

To slide an element down with jQuery, you want the [`slideDown`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) function. For example:

```
function showImage() {
    $('#loadingImage').slideDown();
}
```

As you can see from the link to the `slideDown` documentation, there are many ways you can customize the slide.

```
function showImage() {
    $('#loadingImage').slideDown({
        duration: 400,
        easing: 'swing',
        queue: true,
        specialEasing: {/*key: value...*/},
        step: function(now, tween) {
            // ...
        },
        progress: function(animation, progress, remainingMs) {
            // ...
        },
        complete: function() {
            // ...
        },
        start: function(animation) {
            // ...
        },
        done: function(animation, jumpedToEnd) {
            // ...
        },
        fail: function(animation, jumpedToend) {
            // ...
        },
        always: function(animation, jumpedToend) {
            // ...
        }
    });
}
```

If you don't need much of that, there are a couple smaller variations on the function (all parameters are optional):

```
$('#loadingImage').slideDown(400, function() {
    // complete...
});

$('#loadingImage').slideDown(400, 'swing', function() {
    // complete...
});
```

Core jQuery only offers `'swing'` and `'linear'` for the easing values. Plugings such as jQuery UI can offer additional values. Duration can be a number (in milliseconds) or a string (`'fast'` = 200ms or `'slow'` = 600ms).

Comment: So what would i need to change in the code above, i am very new to using this code and have no idea?

Comment: If you just want the basic slide (which I admit does look nice), you don't need any customization; `$(...).slideDown();` is sufficient. Changing `duration` will let you choose how long the animation takes, and changing `easing` will let you modify the exact animation path. The `complete` callback will let you execute some code when the animation completes, if you need to. You're unlikely to need the other options, but you can check the documentation to see what they do.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
function showImage(){
 $('loadingImage').slideDown();
    var toggleImage = document.getElementById("loadingImage");
      if(toggleImage.style.display == "inline") {
         document.getElementById('loadingImage').style.display='none';
     }else{
        document.getElementById('loadingImage').style.display='inline';
  document.getElementById('loadingImage2').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('loadingImage3').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('loadingImage4').style.display='none';
}
}

Comment: this is the code that i have now and it doesnt work ?

Comment: You're being a bit unclear; what are you _trying_ to accomplish, and what _is_ happening that's actually wrong?

Comment: basically it wont work now, what i want to happen is on a click of image A i want image B to appear, which i got working but then when i try to put the code in to make it slide down it wont work